# JTree expandPath works with File but not with wrapper class

Tags: java, swing, tree, jtree

I wonder what the requirements are so that the `JTree` properly works. I have written some code, displaying a filesystem tree and then call `expandPath()` to expand a path on it.

When I use a File object everything works fine, but the tree shows the full path on each node. So I wrapped it in a class which changes the `toString()` so that only the dir/filename is shown, but now `expandPath()` no longer works and the path is not expanded.

```
package tools.controls.TreeControl.Filesystem;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

public class TreeFile
    extends File
    implements Cloneable
    , Comparable<File>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TreeFile(TreeFile oOther)
    {
        super(oOther.getParentFile(), oOther.getName());
    }

    public TreeFile(File oFile)
    {
        super(oFile.getParentFile(), oFile.getName());
    }

    public TreeFile(String oPath)
    {
        super(oPath);
    }

    public TreeFile(URI oFileURL)
    {
        super(oFileURL);
    }

    public TreeFile(String oParent, String oChild)
    {
        super(oParent, oChild);
    }

    public TreeFile(File oParent, String oChild)
    {
        super(oParent, oChild);
    }

    public TreeFile getParentTreeFile()
    {
        File f = getParentFile();
        if(f == null)
            return null;

        return new TreeFile(f);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return getName();
    }

    public TreeFile clone()
    {
        return new TreeFile(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(File oObject)
    {
        return super.compareTo(oObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"When I use a File object everything works fine, but the tree shows the full path on each node. So.."* ..use a `TreeCellRenderer` specifically made for a `File`! See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for an example.

Comment: That would be something to look into. Still, I would like to understand why it's not working, what is missing in my class so that the tree accepts it?

Comment: Since it's a completely ludicrous way to go about things, I'm not the slightest bit interested in looking into it. Good luck with it!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your behavior.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Would have been nice if you had explained what's wrong with my approach instead of putting such a unfriendly comment. However, your comment about the cell renderer got me in the right direction and it works now, so thanks. This approach looks much better, though I still would like to know why my first attempt didn't work.

Comment: *"I still would like to know why my first attempt didn't work."* (shrug) Maybe the `File` object uses the `toString()` method as part of its functionality in defining a file's path. *"such a unfriendly comment"* I use FB for friends, and already have too many of them. I use SO as a source of, and to promulgate, technical information. *"it works now"* Glad you got it sorted. (Which is merely a statement of fact, as opposed to trying to be nice/friendly.)